# Making an AJAX post call with jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I cannot find any clear examples of what I want. I want to visit *sample.aspx* and want to send it some plain text parameters via `POST` (not query string). If it succeeds, I want to look at the response which will be in JSON. If it fails I want to do stuff to handle it. So I need success and fail functions.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you look at the examples here?: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/  And/or here?: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ What specifically is unclear about them?  We're happy to help, but it's not obvious where you're having difficulty.

Comment: The data part and success are unclear. How do I get my data, and also, how do I submit post args?

Comment: The `data` can be as simple as some key/value pairs in a JSON object.  There are several examples in the "Examples" section of that page.  Those key/value pairs are the POST values.  The `success` function is invoked when the AJAX call succeeds, and is passed the response from the server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var data = ; //POST PARAMS for send 

$.ajax({
    url: '/sample.aspx',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    timeout: 10000,
    dataType: "html",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {

    },
    error: function (error) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

plain text parameters via POST (not query string) .. please elaborate more

let me break this down for you ...

now how does ajax work

1- you send a request (GET / POST ) .

**note : visiting a webpage is a get request**

2- the page outputs a response ..

3- jquery reads the page .. it reads the html of the page ..
so if i were to vist stack overflow with $.ajax , i will get the full front page html ..

here is an example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
  type: "GET",
  data: {id : 'myid'}, // the url will become http://stackoverflow.com?id=myid
  dataType: "html", // what type of response your expecting 
  success : function(e){ // e is the response 
              console.log(e); // the will log the html of stackoverflow
             }
});
```

but if you expect that the data you will be getting is json
then all you have to do on the server side is make the page outputs (display) the json you want as a string and jquery will read it and you can parse it as json

here is a small php example

```
<?php
echo 'hi ' . $_GET['id'] ;
?>
```

using the above jquery code and this page i will get the response

```
'hi myid'
```